# In angular 8, when uplaod the build error occurs due to polyfills-es2015

Tags: angular

In angular 8, When I upload the build error occurs

Error :-

```
polyfills-es2015.db074f152f5fbfd29825.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'true' of undefined
    at Object.6dTf (polyfills-es2015.db074f152f5fbfd29825.js:1)
    at a (runtime-es2015.30fc626ba611e35f5ac3.js:1)
    at Module.hN/g (polyfills-es2015.db074f152f5fbfd29825.js:1)
    at a (runtime-es2015.30fc626ba611e35f5ac3.js:1)
    at Object.1 (polyfills-es2015.db074f152f5fbfd29825.js:1)
    at a (runtime-es2015.30fc626ba611e35f5ac3.js:1)
    at t (runtime-es2015.30fc626ba611e35f5ac3.js:1)
    at Array.r [as push] (runtime-es2015.30fc626ba611e35f5ac3.js:1)
    at polyfills-es2015.db074f152f5fbfd29825.js:1
```

How to resolve this error.

Environment:-

```
Angular CLI: 8.0.1
Node: 10.15.3
OS: linux x64
Angular: 8.0.0
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... platform-server, router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.800.1
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.800.1
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.800.1
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.800.1
@angular-devkit/core              8.0.1
@angular-devkit/schematics        8.0.1
@angular/cli                      8.0.1
@angular/http                     7.2.15
@ngtools/webpack                  8.0.1
@schematics/angular               8.0.1
@schematics/update                0.800.1
rxjs                              6.5.2
typescript                        3.4.5
webpack     4.30.0
```

I am used ng build --prod --aot --build-optimizer command to build the app.

Answer (score 4):

**web-animations-js** published 2.3.2 which includes the fix for this error on angular 8

Answer (score 1):

The problem is coming from **web-animations-js**.

Since Angular 6, it is **no longer needed**:

> We’ve updated our implementation of Animations to no longer need the
>   web animations polyfill. This means that you can remove this polyfill
>   from your application and save approximately 47KB of bundle size,
>   while increasing animations performance in Safari at the same time.

https://angular.io/guide/browser-support#enabling-polyfills

Remove the import from polyfills.ts:

```
import 'web-animations-js';
```

And remove "web-animations-js" from your package.json:

```
"web-animations-js": "^2.3.1"
```

This solved my problem.

The current polyfills.ts from Angular does not contain it anymore:
https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/aio/src/polyfills.ts

Comment: This solved my problem also but in IE 11 browser some page does not showing or that error occurs in IE 11 browser "Unable to get property '0' of undefined or null reference"

Comment: I cannot help you with that, sorry - luckily I don't have to support IE11 !

Answer (score 0):

Angular 8 has the breaking changes with the versions of **typescript** and **Node**

**typescript** version should be 3.4

**Node** version should be 12 or later

Comment: Thanks, I have update the node latest version but that solution does not work for me

Answer (score -2):

polyfills-es2015.94d3ba46aae3a65c2d88.js:2          GET http://localhost:3000/api/stuff 404 (Not Found)
_ @ polyfills-es2015.94d3ba46aae3a65c2d88.js:2
scheduleTask @ polyfills-es2015.94d3ba46aae3a65c2d88.js:2
onScheduleTask @ polyfills-es2015.94d3ba46aae3a65c2d88.js:2
scheduleTask @ polyfills-es2015.94d3ba46aae3a65c2d88.js:2
scheduleTask @ polyfills-es2015.94d3ba46aae3a65c2d88.js:2
scheduleMacroTask @ polyfills-es2015.94d3ba46aae3a65c2d88.js:2
u @ polyfills-es2015.94d3ba46aae3a65c2d88.js:2
(anonymous) @ polyfills-es2015.94d3ba46aae3a65c2d88.js:2
s. @ polyfills-es2015.94d3ba46aae3a65c2d88.js:2
(anonymous) @ main-es2015.bd44af9c4a4f085f43e6.js:2
_trySubscribe @ main-es2015.bd44af9c4a4f085f43e6.js:2
subscribe @ main-es2015.bd44af9c4a4f085f43e6.js:2
$ @ main-es2015.bd44af9c4a4f085f43e6.js:2
_innerSub @ main-es2015.bd44af9c4a4f085f43e6.js:2
_tryNext @ main-es2015.bd44af9c4a4f085f43e6.js:2
_next @ main-es2015.bd44af9c4a4f085f43e6.js:2
next @ main-es2015.bd44af9c4a4f085f43e6.js:2
(anonymous) @ main-es2015.bd44af9c4a4f085f43e6.js:2
_trySubscribe @ main-es2015.bd44af9c4a4f085f43e6.js:2
subscribe @ main-es2015.bd44af9c4a4f085f43e6.js:2
call @ main-es2015.bd44af9c4a4f085f43e6.js:2
subscribe @ main-es2015.bd44af9c4a4f085f43e6.js:2
call @ main-es2015.bd44af9c4a4f085f43e6.js:2
subscribe @ main-es2015.bd44af9c4a4f085f43e6.js:2
call @ main-es2015.bd44af9c4a4f085f43e6.js:2
subscribe @ main-es2015.bd44af9c4a4f085f43e6.js:2
getStuff @ main-es2015.bd44af9c4a4f085f43e6.js:2
ngOnInit @ main-es2015.bd44af9c4a4f085f43e6.js:2
(anonymous) @ main-es2015.bd44af9c4a4f085f43e6.js:2
(anonymous) @ main-es2015.bd44af9c4a4f085f43e6.js:2
no @ main-es2015.bd44af9c4a4f085f43e6.js:2
Ao @ main-es2015.bd44af9c4a4f085f43e6.js:2
(anonymous) @ main-es2015.bd44af9c4a4f085f43e6.js:2
updateDirectives @ main-es2015.bd44af9c4a4f085f43e6.js:2
to @ main-es2015.bd44af9c4a4f085f43e6.js:2
co @ main-es2015.bd44af9c4a4f085f43e6.js:2
uo @ main-es2015.bd44af9c4a4f085f43e6.js:2
to @ main-es2015.bd44af9c4a4f085f43e6.js:2
co @ main-es2015.bd44af9c4a4f085f43e6.js:2
ao @ main-es2015.bd44af9c4a4f085f43e6.js:2
to @ main-es2015.bd44af9c4a4f085f43e6.js:2
co @ main-es2015.bd44af9c4a4f085f43e6.js:2
uo @ main-es2015.bd44af9c4a4f085f43e6.js:2
to @ main-es2015.bd44af9c4a4f085f43e6.js:2
co @ main-es2015.bd44af9c4a4f085f43e6.js:2
ao @ main-es2015.bd44af9c4a4f085f43e6.js:2
to @ main-es2015.bd44af9c4a4f085f43e6.js:2
detectChanges @ main-es2015.bd44af9c4a4f085f43e6.js:2
tick @ main-es2015.bd44af9c4a4f085f43e6.js:2
(anonymous) @ main-es2015.bd44af9c4a4f085f43e6.js:2
invoke @ polyfills-es2015.94d3ba46aae3a65c2d88.js:2
onInvoke @ main-es2015.bd44af9c4a4f085f43e6.js:2
invoke @ polyfills-es2015.94d3ba46aae3a65c2d88.js:2
run @ polyfills-es2015.94d3ba46aae3a65c2d88.js:2
run @ main-es2015.bd44af9c4a4f085f43e6.js:2
next @ main-es2015.bd44af9c4a4f085f43e6.js:2
r @ main-es2015.bd44af9c4a4f085f43e6.js:2
__tryOrUnsub @ main-es2015.bd44af9c4a4f085f43e6.js:2
next @ main-es2015.bd44af9c4a4f085f43e6.js:2
_next @ main-es2015.bd44af9c4a4f085f43e6.js:2
next @ main-es2015.bd44af9c4a4f085f43e6.js:2
next @ main-es2015.bd44af9c4a4f085f43e6.js:2
emit @ main-es2015.bd44af9c4a4f085f43e6.js:2
Gs @ main-es2015.bd44af9c4a4f085f43e6.js:2
onHasTask @ main-es2015.bd44af9c4a4f085f43e6.js:2
hasTask @ polyfills-es2015.94d3ba46aae3a65c2d88.js:2
_updateTaskCount @ polyfills-es2015.94d3ba46aae3a65c2d88.js:2
_updateTaskCount @ polyfills-es2015.94d3ba46aae3a65c2d88.js:2
runTask @ polyfills-es2015.94d3ba46aae3a65c2d88.js:2
_ @ polyfills-es2015.94d3ba46aae3a65c2d88.js:2
Promise.then (async)
g @ polyfills-es2015.94d3ba46aae3a65c2d88.js:2
scheduleTask @ polyfills-es2015.94d3ba46aae3a65c2d88.js:2
onScheduleTask @ polyfills-es2015.94d3ba46aae3a65c2d88.js:2
scheduleTask @ polyfills-es2015.94d3ba46aae3a65c2d88.js:2
scheduleTask @ polyfills-es2015.94d3ba46aae3a65c2d88.js:2
scheduleMicroTask @ polyfills-es2015.94d3ba46aae3a65c2d88.js:2
E @ polyfills-es2015.94d3ba46aae3a65c2d88.js:2
then @ polyfills-es2015.94d3ba46aae3a65c2d88.js:2
appInitializer @ main-es2015.bd44af9c4a4f085f43e6.js:2
runInitializers @ main-es2015.bd44af9c4a4f085f43e6.js:2
(anonymous) @ main-es2015.bd44af9c4a4f085f43e6.js:2
(anonymous) @ main-es2015.bd44af9c4a4f085f43e6.js:2
(anonymous) @ main-es2015.bd44af9c4a4f085f43e6.js:2
invoke @ polyfills-es2015.94d3ba46aae3a65c2d88.js:2
onInvoke @ main-es2015.bd44af9c4a4f085f43e6.js:2
invoke @ polyfills-es2015.94d3ba46aae3a65c2d88.js:2
run @ polyfills-es2015.94d3ba46aae3a65c2d88.js:2
run @ main-es2015.bd44af9c4a4f085f43e6.js:2
bootstrapModuleFactory @ main-es2015.bd44af9c4a4f085f43e6.js:2
zUnb @ main-es2015.bd44af9c4a4f085f43e6.js:2
l @ runtime-es2015.cdfb0ddb511f65fdc0a0.js:1
0 @ main-es2015.bd44af9c4a4f085f43e6.js:2
l @ runtime-es2015.cdfb0ddb511f65fdc0a0.js:1
t @ runtime-es2015.cdfb0ddb511f65fdc0a0.js:1
r @ runtime-es2015.cdfb0ddb511f65fdc0a0.js:1
(anonymous) @ main-es2015.bd44af9c4a4f085f43e6.js:2
Show 40 more frames
main-es2015.bd44af9c4a4f085f43e6.js:2 ep {headers: Hd, status: 404, statusText: 'Not Found', url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/stuff', ok: false, …}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).